# Rails - Pre select multiple options with grouped_options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionviewhelper

I would like to preselect multiple options when using grouped_options_for_select in rails 4.1

The method signature is

```
grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options, selected_key= = nil, options = {})
```

The selected_key only allows a single value which matches exact options. I would like to preselect multiple options since i am using a multi-select. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `selected_key` an array of values for exactly your case.

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select):

> "selected may also be an array of values to be selected when using a
>   multiple select."

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef0f633c66d8eac6612c118c66ccf1b096bd4d3e/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L526) for `grouped_options_for_select` it just calls `options_for_select` passing `selected_key`.